# How to create geom_rect() based on different x variable for histogram plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset for which I am creating a `histogram`. I have another variable `rect_grade` mapped to the x variable i.e `a` used to create `histogram`. So how can I use this `rect_grade` col to create **color shaded rectangular sections** on top of `histogram` ?

**data**

```
library(tidyverse)

demo = tibble(a = c(10,20,50,35,80,25,95,16,55,65,40,85,37))

# Another variable that was created based on above variable
demo = demo %>% 
  mutate(rect_grade = ifelse(a<10, 1, 
                        ifelse(a>=10 & a <30, 2,
                               ifelse(a>=30 & a <50, 3,
                                      ifelse(a>=50 & a <70, 4,
                                             ifelse(a>=70 & a <90, 5,
                                                    ifelse(a>=90, 6,7)))))))
```

**Histogram Plot:**

```
ggplot(data = demo, aes(x = a)) +
  
  # this is just a random binwidth
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 15)
```

[image]

Now I would like to create color shaded rect regions on top of this hitogram plot based on `rect_grade` variable that I have created but I am not sure how to map these two variables together.

This is just a reference pic of result which is not based on this data:
[image]

(Open to use any other method & not restricted to just `geom_rect()`)

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: How do you expect that the shaded area look on your histogram? What should they tell you?

Comment: X axis should remain the same .. just that partitions should be there by different colors and later i should be able to add text/ annotate to it for rect_grade as label name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the breaks for the intervals in a `data.frame`, then use this dataset for `geom_rect`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

demo <- data.frame(a = c(10, 20, 50, 35, 80, 25, 95, 16, 55, 65, 40, 85, 37))

breaks <- c(-Inf, seq(10, 90, 20), Inf)

rects <- data.frame(
  xmin = breaks[-length(breaks)],
  xmax = breaks[-1],
  rect_grade = seq_along(breaks[-1])
)

ggplot(data = demo, aes(x = a)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 15) +
  geom_rect(
    data = rects,
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, fill = factor(rect_grade)),
    ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = .2, inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks)
```

[image]